# Alternative for VSBuild@1 in GitHub Actions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions, azure-pipelines-yaml

While converting an Azure DevOps Pipeline YAML file, I came across a task that utilizes `VSBuild@1` in the following snippet as follows:

```
-task: VSBuild@1
    inputs: 
        solution: '**\**\*.sqlproj'
        configuration: '$BuildConfiguration'
        displayName: 'Visual Studio Build Database Project'
```

I am migrating such pipelines to Github Actions YAML Format. How do I translate it to Github Actions?

What is the GitHub Action equivalent of VSBuild@1?